# Vue.js : "Invalid or unexpected token" when using webpack.DefinePlugin()

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, webkit

Honestly.. i'm a bit new to node and process.env stuff.. There is probably a perfectly good explanation somewhere to what i'm asking but i haven't found it yet..

**The Task :**

Storing username and password in a env.js file so i can check against those in my store.js file...

**Current approach :**

> webpack.base.conf.js

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')
var webpack = require('webpack');

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        loginEmail: "xxxxx",
        loginPw: "xxxxxx"
      }
    })
  ],
.... rest is default/unchanged
```

**Error :**

[image]

I haven't gotten to the part where i actually access the process.env.loginEmail yet, but i assume it's like this (either in component or store.js) :

```
console.log("Process listings ==>")
console.log("loginEmail : " + process.env.loginEmail)
```

Comment: You have to either wrap the strings in additional (alternated) quotes or use `JSON.stringify`: check the blue tip at the docs: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: Checking it right away :) Keep you posted in a minute...

Comment: Worked magically !.. Would love to accept this as correct answer, so if you put up an answer i will :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [DefinePlugin docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#usage):

> Note that because the plugin does a direct text replacement, the value
>   given to it must include **actual quotes** inside of the string itself.
>   Typically, this is done either with either alternate quotes, such as
>   `'"production"'`, or by using `JSON.stringify('production')`.

So, change your code to:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    loginEmail: "'xxxxx'",
    loginPw: "'xxxxxx'"
  }
})
```

or

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    loginEmail: JSON.stringify("xxxxx"),
    loginPw: JSON.stringify("xxxxxx")
  }
})
```